# Finding the limit of $x \sin\frac{\pi}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find the limit of the following

$x\rightarrow\infty$

$x \sin\frac{\pi}{x}$

I did

$\dfrac{\sin\frac{\pi}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}$

I took the derivative using l hospital and got.

$\dfrac{-1x^{-2} \cos \dfrac{\pi}{x}}{-1x^{-2}}$

Simplying I get

$\cos \frac{\pi}{x}$ but I am stuck.

another problem I have is

$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\cot x}$ as $x\rightarrow0$

I did

$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{-\csc^2(x)}$

But I am unsure how to go on.

Comment: I suspect that the title of your question needs correcting. $x\sin \tfrac{\pi}{2} \equiv x$.

Comment: yes sorry ill correct it

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be closed, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?). *(note, I upvoted this question, as you have shown work. The fact remains that you should ask separate questions...)*

Comment: When you took the derivative of $\sin$, you forgot to carry the $\pi$ along.  The derivative of the numerator is $- \frac{\pi \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{x} \right)}{x^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so now you want to evaluate

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)
$$

what is $\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\pi}{x}$? What do you get if you plug that into $\cos$?

For the second limit, you can rewrite it as

$$
-\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x} = -\sin(x) \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}
$$

You should know what $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is, and then use 'limit of product is product of limits'.

Comment: (you might want to use \dfrac instead of \frac, so that your fractions are legible! You can see an example in the source of this question)

Comment: would I plug zero into cos and get 1 for my my limit

Comment: @FernandoMartinez yes, that's exactly what you should do. good work

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 you mean for the inline expressions? Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Hmm for the second one how do you mean I shoudld turn -csc^2 into -1/sin^2

Comment: Yes, exactly; by definition $\csc(x) = 1/\sin(x)$, and so $-1/\csc^2(x) = -\sin^2(x)$.

Comment: sin(x)/x when you plug the limit zero is one I think

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So the final limit is therefore zero.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Simply introduce a new variable $t = 1/x$, then the problem becomes $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\dfrac{\sin\pi t}t$ which you know the answer ($\pi$).

Answer (score 0):

For problems like this you can expand sine in terms of the following taylor series:

$$ sin (p) = p - \frac{p^3}{3!} + \frac{p^5}{5!} - \frac{p^7}{7!} + ...$$

Substituting $p = \frac{\pi}{x}$, we get:

$sin(\frac{\pi}{x}) = \frac{\pi}{x} - \frac{\pi^3}{x^3 3!} + \frac{\pi^5}{x^5 3!} - ...$

We are evaluating $f(x) = x \space sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$, so if we multiply above by $x$, we see that the first term is $\pi$, the other terms are powers of $\frac{1}{x}$

Hence when you apply the limit, the answer tends to $\pi$